# Python - Dataframe Currency Conversion

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I have a data frame that I created by merging two data frames that looks like this:

```
Salary Amount:    Salary Currency:   Country Origin:    Exchange Rate: 
 55000.0           EUR                 EUR               1.195826
 200000.0          USD                 USD               1.000000
 130000.0          GBP                 GBP               1.324188
```

There are lots more currencies in the data frame this is just an example. I want to multiply the salary amount with the exchange rate GBP to have the British Pounds (GBP) for every row in the data frame. I also want to print out the maximum and median salary in GBP. I assume I have to times the salary amount with exchange rate but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: So, you want to multiply all the 3 rows with the "Exchange Rate" in the 3rd row (GBP), is that right?

Comment: I would like to convert the salary amount into GBP.

Comment: @MrStewart please check my answer below if this is what you are expecting. It will be great if you can post a sample of what you are expecting for us to help you better

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to multiply all the 3 rows with the "Exchange Rate" in the 3rd row (GBP) - you can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[55000.0,'EUR','EUR',1.195826],
                   [200000.0,'USD','USD',1.000000],
                   [130000.0,'GBP','GBP',1.324188]],
                  columns=['Salary Amount:','Salary Currency:','Country Origin:','Exchange Rate:'])

# get the GBP exchange rate in the variable exchange_rate_GBP 
exchange_rate_GBP = df[df['Salary Currency:']=='GBP']['Exchange Rate:'].values

# create a new column and multiply the `Salary Amount:` column value with the `exchange_rate_GBP` value
df['converted'] = df['Salary Amount:']*exchange_rate_GBP
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Salary Amount: Salary Currency: Country Origin:  Exchange Rate:  converted
0         55000.0              EUR             EUR        1.195826   72830.34
1        200000.0              USD             USD        1.000000  264837.60
2        130000.0              GBP             GBP        1.324188  172144.44
```

If you dont want to convert the 3rd row which is already in GBP you can use `np.where()` and ignore that row

```
df['converted'] = np.where(df['Salary Currency:']!='GBP', 
                           df['Salary Amount:']*exchange_rate_GBP, 
                           df['Salary Amount:'])
```

Output: (3rd row which is in GBP is not converted)

```
   Salary Amount: Salary Currency: Country Origin:  Exchange Rate:  converted
0         55000.0              EUR             EUR        1.195826   72830.34
1        200000.0              USD             USD        1.000000  264837.60
2        130000.0              GBP             GBP        1.324188  130000.00
```

To get mean and max:

```
print("Mean: ", df['converted'].mean())
print("Max: ", df['converted'].max())
```

Output:

```
Mean:  169937.46
Max:  264837.6
```